How to get form values submitted over widget imbedded
The following script is the code i got from another service and i need to utilize submitted form fields elsewhere:
<script src="https://akiba-enterprise-widget-prod.web.app//Widget.js"></script>

    <script>
      const config = { 
        secretKey:"....", 
        embedUrl: window.location.href, 
        displayStyle: "fixed" 
      };
    window.widget.init(config);

</script>


$("#dummy").myDummyWidget();

var widget = $("#dummy").data("myDummyWidget");
$("#dummy").myDummyWidget("hide")
widget. Hide();


Welcome to Stack Overflow. This script would be run in the browser after the page is received. So I am not sure how this script would "utilize submitted form fields". I do not see any form fields or form data in this example. Please provide a [mcve].
